# How to start separate processes

Tags: c#, wpf, process

How to start separate processes integrated in one wpf application in c# and how to communicate between them?
What I want is somthing [like Internet Explorer](http://techie-buzz.com/browsers/ie8-creates-separate-processes-for-each-tab.html).

In this case I want to Integerate several applications into one individual application with separate processes

Comment: Why do you want to have separate processes?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Having separate processes will most likely hurt maintainability, not help it, because you have to maintain the code that manages inter-process communication. And I think whatever flexibility you think you would gain, you could have while using just one process.

Comment: take look at [here](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/multi-process-architecture)

Comment: You'd probably be interested in WCF + Named Pipes for interprocess communication. It's worked well for me on a number of occasions. If performance is critical, then shared memory might be more appropriate.

Comment: @Navid, that doesn't say anything about maintainability or flexibility. Are you building something like a browser, i.e. are you going to run others' code? Because if not, I think having more processes is not the best option.

Comment: @Navid, I wasn't asking what are the benefits of this architecture in general. I was asking what exactly are your reasons for considering this.

Comment: We work on a large system with different languages and we need to integrate them

Comment: @Navid: Different .NET languages (in which case you can just reference the other assemblies from your WPF project and don't need individual processes at all), or different non-.NET languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process_methods.aspx) class and [named pipes](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/dotnet-35-adds-named-pipes-support).
But, generally, this would hurt the maintenability (see other responses).
For processes running on different machines, you better have a look at WCF.